# Class implementing ServletContainerInitializer in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web.xml

Can you point to a class implementing the `ServletContainerInitializer` interface in the `web.xml` file or do you have to add a file under the `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` to have a J2EE server pick it up?

If it's possible via the `web.xml` file, please explain how.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've checked the [Java Servlet Specification 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) and I've not found any clue that it could be configured via `web.xml`. I think the only way is the 
`META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file.

Please note that the `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` is a file (not a directory) which has to contain the fully qualified name of the initalizer, like:

```
com.example.MyServletContainerInitializer
```

It could be inside the war too (tested with Tomcat 7.0.21).

Here is a complete example: http://nullhaus.com/2011/03/using-servlets-3-0-servletcontainerinitializer/

Comment: Thanks... I already knew this but was hoping that it could be done in the web.xml. I'll thump up and accept your post anyway.

Comment: To further confirm, it is _not_ possible to configure a `ServletContainerInitializer` in the `web.xml`. From the _Servlet 3.0 Spec, 8.2.4_:

" An instance of the `ServletContainerInitializer` is looked up via the jar services API by the container at container / application startup time. The framework providing an implementation of the `ServletContainerInitializer` MUST bundle in the `META-INF/services directory` of the jar file a file called `javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer`, as per the jar services API, that points to the implementation class of the `ServletContainerInitializer`. "

Comment: Dead link on nullhaus.com , here's where that page lives now: http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/03/using-servlets-3-0-servletcontainerinitializer/