# Tomcat 7 - unable to load class X warnings

Tags: tomcat7

Lately I've noticed that after deploying a web application to Tomcat 7 from Eclipse, I'm getting 30+ warnings in the Catalina log file that look like the following:

> Oct 17, 2011 3:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig
>   checkHandlesTypes WARNING: Unable to load class
>   [com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass$1] to check against the @HandlesTypes
>   annotation of one or more ServletContentInitializers. 
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass$1     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.checkHandlesTypes(ContextConfig.java:1969)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:1932)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1826)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1785)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1771)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1254)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:881)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:316)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:812)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:787)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:607)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:932)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:723)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:470)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:324)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:774)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1033)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:727)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
>     at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:620)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:303)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:431)

The application still works fine, it's just a pain to have to scroll past all these warnings to get to debugging lines.  Any idea on how to fix these warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out that the jaxb-xjc.jar wasn't needed for deployment so I just ended up removing it from the classpath which ended up getting rid of all the warning messages.

Answer (score 3):

The following forum post also outlines a problem that occurs when using Metro 2.1.1 with Servlet 3.0 WebApps - may also be of value:
http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/metro-211-and-servlet-version-30-tomcat-many-startup-errors

Comment: The solution (add `metadata-complete="true"` to the `<web-app />` tag in web.xml) worked for me!

Comment: add metadata-complete="true" to the <web-app /> tag in web.xml worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Check your dependencies. One (or more) of them contain `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file. This file contains class names of type [`ServletContainerInitializer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer.html). `ServletContainerInitializer`s usually have `@HandlesTypes` annotation which refers classes. One of the referred classes imports/use `com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass` which is not on your webapp's classpath.

This question also could be useful: [Class implementing ServletContainerInitializer in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680860/class-implementing-servletcontainerinitializer-in-web-xml/7684756)

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look at the linked question.  So far the whole ServletContainerInitializer file seems pretty complicated even after going through the tutorial.

Comment: I checked my classpath and I've included the JAR file jaxb-xjc which contains com.sun.codemodel.JArrayClass.  I'm using Eclipse (Indigo) to compile and package everything to copy over to Tomcat.  It looks like the error only has to do with Servlet 3.0 because if I change my web.xml webapp version to 2.5 I don't get the warnings anymore.

Comment: `ServletContainerInitializer` was introduced in Servlet/webapp 3.0. In 2.5 they are not used and your `META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer` file is ignored by Tomcat so it does not throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with tomcat version 7.0.23. I didn't notice this issue after I switched to Tomcat 7.0.33.

Even when I just replaced ${tomcat.dir}/lib/*jars with the jars from the latest tomcat, the problem was  solved.

Alternatively, if it helps
two other solutions work

1. Modify web.xml for every war in webapps and change the web-app version to 2.5 from 3.0
   or
2. Add metadata-complete=true to web-app tag